# Value undefined inside Callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic.js to access ElasticSearch and run query.... I need to run a facet and get the result and use this result for another query... I'm able to get the result of first one and run query using the result, but not able to access the 1st query term inside the second callback due to the problem with execution sequence. If I use setTimeout() of JS im able to get desired result.

So is there any better alternative to setTimeout  ??

```
for(i in res_week){ 
        if(res_week[i].term !=null){
            var sourceFilter = ejs.TermsFilter("source",res_week[i].term);
                var data2 = [];
                var term_temp = res_week[i].term;
                var count_temp = res_week[i].count;
                var typesCallback = function(typeResults){

                    console.log(typeResults);
                    var temphold = typeResults.facets.srctype_list.terms;
                    data2.push(temphold);
                    console.log(term_temp);


                };
                data.push({"list":data2});
                var temp_r = ejs.Request()
                        .indices(index)  
                        .types(type)
                        .facet(listfacet
            .facetFilter(ejs.AndFilter([timeLimit,sourceFilter])));

                console.log(temp_r);
                temp_r.doSearch(typesCallback);



                        }
```

Here I'm not able to access res_week[] 's terms inside typesCallback function and it says undefined, by using a temporary variable i get those terms inside the function but not in the first iteration, but from second iteration only.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @ArunPJohny code added

Answer (score 0):

If you need the first callback to run before the second callback, put your second filter call in the first callback.

Your code (reordered):

```
for(i in res_week){ 
    if(res_week[i].term !=null){
        var sourceFilter = ejs.TermsFilter("source",res_week[i].term);
        var data2 = [];
        var term_temp = res_week[i].term;
        var count_temp = res_week[i].count;
        var typesCallback = function(typeResults){

            console.log(typeResults);
            var temphold = typeResults.facets.srctype_list.terms;
            data2.push(temphold);
            console.log(term_temp);

            data.push({"list":data2});

            var temp_r = ejs.Request()
                    .indices(index)  
                    .types(type)
                    .facet(listfacet.facetFilter(ejs.AndFilter([timeLimit,sourceFilter])));

            console.log(temp_r);

        };

        temp_r.doSearch(typesCallback);
    }
}
```

Comment: that was the 1st thing i did, I had put the second filter inside the 1st callback, and there i need to loop inside the callback using the 1st result, and the 1st iteration of the loop fires an error saying "value undefined". and that is why i tried this outside function calls using timeout, using timeout it works for me but i need to avoid using setTimeout.....

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Instead of using setTimeout, i have made a different function and called that function at the end of callback with required result as the passing parameter.
and this brought the filters out from the first callback too.

Thanks for the responses guys. :)